# Replacement for addVersionToProjectName (maven-eclipse-plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'd like to import two maven multi-module projects of different versions into one eclipse workspace.

For this purpose I could manually set a name template while importing the projects using the *Import Existing Maven Projects* wizard. In my opinion, a simpler solution would be to use the *maven-eclipse-plugin* to set *addVersionToProjectName* to *true* per *pom.xml*, but according to this [link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#addVersionToProjectName), this plugin has been marked as retired in 2015.

Is there any good substitution available to configure the eclipse project name while importing projects into eclipse?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How often do you encounter this problem? It seems like something that you can easily solve with the wizard unless you import projects five times a day.

Comment: First which Eclipse version do you use? You should use Eclipse and import the project simply.

Comment: Currently we use Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0). Yes, I know, we could do it manually using the wizard. We don't need it daily, but since we split out project into separate multiple GIT repos being involved in about 3-4 releases per year I thought about simplifying our workflow (where the former maven-eclipse-plugin would have helped). Thank you anyway for your comments.